# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500 says

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, http-options-method

I have a web api in asp.net 4.5. I have installed nuget package for cors
and made corresponding code changes

in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.EnableCors();
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In the controller

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:56241/api/loancopy/3219795539", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/loancopy")]
public class MainController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{loannumber}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostLoanCopy([FromUri]string loanNumber, [FromBody] LoanDto LoanDto)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage();
    }
}
```

This is my client side post request in angular2

```
export class HeroService {
    private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:56241/api/loancopy/3219795539';
    private body = 'body'
      constructor(private http: Http) { }

    addHero(name: Loan): Observable<Loan> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify(Loan), options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

My client says Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Comment: Could you try with `origins: "http://localhost:56241/` alone for the origins and route as `[Route("{loanNumber}")]`

Comment: This means your server couldn't handle the request. Perhaps you need to configure it to properly respond to `OPTIONS` requests.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I presume you followed [this documentation](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#allowed-origins)

I'm finding it strange that the URL your client calls is exactly the same as the url declared as acceptable origins:

Angular2:

```
private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:56241/api/loancopy/3219795539';
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:56241/api/loancopy/3219795539", ...
```

The `origins` parameter is used to indicate from which hosts do you accept incomming requests, and the value you seem to be using is the exact same host as the `.net` application is running. Consider changing it to the host you are accessing your `angular2`aplication.

For example, if you are running it in `localhost`, on port `3000`, the `EnableCors` declaration should be the following:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:3000", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Also, as [@Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5665484/developer) noted, the `origin` declaration should not contain the path, just the host.

So use something like `origins: http://localhost:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000/path/to/angular/page`